# Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid resource field value in the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I am following a [List Queues sample](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/samples/cloud-tasks-list-queues#cloud_tasks_list_queues-nodejs) to lists all the queues. But, I get below error:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid resource field value in the request.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:190:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:365:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:188:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

Some code snippet:

```
const parent = client.locationPath(project, location);
const [queues] = await client.listQueues({parent});

if (queues.length > 0) {
  console.log('Queues:');
  queues.forEach(queue => {
    console.log(` ${queue.name}`);
  });
} else {
  console.log('No queues found!');
}
```

I am not very sure whether the error is derived from this line:

```
const [queues] = await client.listQueues({parent});
```

Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you refer to this [Github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/issues/506), the error seems to be due to a misinformed request: and it will be helpful if you share some code snippet to further debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks @SandeepVokkareni, please refer to the updated code snippet above.

Comment: Thanks @SandeepVokkareni, the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change

```
const [queues] = await client.listQueues({parent});
```

to

```
const [queues] = await client.listQueues({parent: parent});
```

and the problem is solved.